# (Gvim) How to delete a certain pattern which is embraced by certain characters

Tags: vim

I like to delete all characters embraced by "[" and "]" including these embracing characters.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use a find and replace like this:

```
:%s/\[.*\]//g
```

Comment: Thanks. From your question, I can assume a few things.
\\[ refers "[" and .* refers all characters. but if I use \\*, it refers *.
Am I right? But what about removing lines without "new line"?

Comment: Yes you're right. But sorry, I don't get your next question, however, it cannot delete all character embraced by '[' and ']' if there is a newline on it. :%s/\\[[a-zA-Z0-9 \n]*\]//g can. (Assuming your embraced characters contains only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, spaces, and newlines). reference: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: Sorry. That was -without leaving "new line"-. Anyway, I solved this problem by myself. Thanks again.

Comment: @bilo Better to use `\_[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9 \n]`. Reason: when writing `[…\n]` you may think that `[^…\n]` will match anything except characters in `…` and newline. This is false, `[^…\n]` will match *newline and* all characters not from `…`. `\_[^…]`/`\_[…]` makes it clearer what is going on: that `\n` in the collection is not a character, but some sort of modifier that extends collection with a newline.

Answer (score 8):

Believe it or not, `da[`. Read `:help text-objects` to find out why, and what other kinds of regions you can use in this way (some other useful ones are `aw` for a word, and `ap` for a paragraph).